# Strange error sets value to nil until I restart server then it reverts value to orig value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In all of my years of Rails dev, I have never encountered an issue like this.

If I run an Update action, i.e. `Node#Update`, it seems to successfully run, this is the log:

```
Started PATCH "/nodes/35" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-06 19:25:45 -0500
Processing by NodesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"F1HGLwIjDG3VaIYlnsu7NbROEiWBO8xqJtjh5MreI9E=", "node"=>{"name"=>"Testy", "parents"=>"37", "family_tree_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Update Node", "id"=>"35"}
  Node Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 35]]
   (0.9ms)  BEGIN
  Node Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 37]]
   (1.0ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/nodes/35
Completed 302 Found in 13ms (ActiveRecord: 3.9ms)
```

But then if I go back to the `Node#Edit`, I get this error:

```
Started GET "/nodes/35/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-06 19:32:39 -0500
Processing by NodesController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"35"}
  Node Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 35]]
  FamilyTree Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "family_trees".* FROM "family_trees"  WHERE "family_trees"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Node Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."family_tree_id" = $1  [["family_tree_id", 2]]
  Rendered nodes/_form.html.erb (13.0ms)
  Rendered nodes/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (14.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 19ms

TypeError - no implicit conversion of nil into Array:
```

That is on this line in the `_form.html.erb` partial:

```
<%= f.input :parents, collection: (@node.family_tree.nodes - @node.parents - [@node]).uniq, label: "Parent 1" %>
```

I have Better Errors installed, so when I dig into it, what is happening is `@node.parents` is being returned as nil. Likewise, so does `@node.parent, @node.parent_ids, @node.parent_id`. None of which should be returning as `nil`.

The weird thing is that if I fire up the console at this point and check those values I don't get `nil`, I get the legit values:

```
[1] pry(main)> n = Node.find(35)
  Node Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 35]]
=> #<Node id: 35, family_tree_id: 2, created_at: "2015-01-28 23:17:36", updated_at: "2015-01-28 23:17:36", name: "Testy", ancestry: "13", ancestry_depth: 0, max_tree_depth: 0>
[2] pry(main)> n.parents
  Node Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
=> [#<Node id: 13, family_tree_id: 2, created_at: "2015-01-17 23:18:46", updated_at: "2015-01-17 23:18:46", name: "Jack", ancestry: nil, ancestry_depth: 0, max_tree_depth: 0>]
```

Once I restart the server, and change nothing in the DB, it all works:

```
Started POST "/__better_errors/7243596af02cef24/eval" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-06 19:33:01 -0500
^CStopping ...
Exiting
MGs-Puter:ancestry_app $ rails s
Please require the stackprof gem falling back to fast_stack
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.1.6 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Thin web server (v1.6.3 codename Protein Powder)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop


Started GET "/nodes/35/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-06 20:01:59 -0500
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by NodesController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"35"}
  Node Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 35]]
  FamilyTree Load (5.7ms)  SELECT  "family_trees".* FROM "family_trees"  WHERE "family_trees"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Node Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
  Node Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."family_tree_id" = $1  [["family_tree_id", 2]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
  CACHE (0.4ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
  FamilyTree Load (37.4ms)  SELECT "family_trees".* FROM "family_trees"
  Rendered nodes/_form.html.erb (220.5ms)
  Rendered nodes/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (264.4ms)
  User Load (8.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 790ms (Views: 680.5ms | ActiveRecord: 80.0ms)
```

This is my `NodesController#Update`:

```
  def update
    @node.update(node_params)
    respond_with(@node)
  end

  private
    def set_node
      @node = Node.find(params[:id])
    end

    def node_params
      params.require(:node).permit(:user_id, :family_tree_id, :name, :description, :parent_id, :parent, :parents)
    end
```

What could be causing this weird behavior? Not sure if it matters, but I am using a local forked version of the ancestry gem - that I am modifying - to set & check the `parents` value.

**Edit 1**

This is my `NodeController#Edit`:

```
  def edit
  end
```

**Edit 2**

Before action at the top of my `NodesController`:

```
before_action :set_node, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Comment: What does your `edit` action look like?

Comment: Is there a before action calling set node?

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom Yep...added.